# Trouble with extracting times from schedule using regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I am programming a function that will extract the different times from a schedule using regular expressions in Python. Here is an example of the schedule that I got from a website using BeautifulSoup:

> Interactive talk with discussion17:00-18:00 Documentary ‘Occupy Gezi’
>   We present to you Taksim Gezi park boycott with all ways; day and
>   night, with good sides and bad sides18.00 - 19:00 Poet Maria van
>   Daalen ‘Haitian Vodoo’, poet from Querido publishers19:00
>   Food20:30-22:30

As shown above, the input text has starting times with and without ending times. There is also inconsistency with using either “:” or “.” when separating the hours from the minutes.

Using regex101, I have made the following (very ugly) regular expression that seems to work on all different times: `\d\d[:|.]\d\d(\s*.\s*\d\d[:|.]\d\d)?`

To search the text on Python I use the following code:

```
def extract_times(string):
    list_of_times = re.findall('\d\d[:|.]\d\d(\s*.\s*\d\d[:|.]\d\d)?', string)
    return list_of_times
```

However, when I put the example text from above in this function, it returns this:

```
['-18:00', ' - 19:00', '', '-22:30']
```

I expected something like  `[’17:00-18:00’], [’19:00’]`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: i don't know pyton but think that problem with capturing groups. Try this `(\d\d[:|.]\d\d(?:\s*-\s*\d\d[:|.]\d\d)?)`

Comment: IT WORKED!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one : `\d{1,2}[:.]([\d\s-]+[:.])?\d{2}}`

**Explanation**

`\d{1,2}` one or two digits to match 1:00 and 01:00

`[:.]` to match 18:00 and 18.00

`[\d\s-]+` *n* digit, whitespace or dash *(optional)*

`[:.]\d{2}` to match 18:00 and 18.00 *(optional)*

`\d{2}` 2 digits

In your sample text, the following will match (use full match) :

Match 1 `17:00-18:00`
Match 2 `18.00 - 19:00`
Match 3 `19:00`
Match 4 `20:30-22:30`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h7fxzA/2)